# Golang MongoDB insertMany if not exist

Tags: mongodb, go

So I am writing code where I want to insert many articles to the MongoDB, but I want to check if there are no articles with the same ID and skip them if there are. I can not find an implementation of this logic online can anyone help me with a solution?

`collection.InsertMany` works fine, but it does not check for existing documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '$setOnInsert'.
Like this :

```
db.products.update(
  {  },
  {
     $set: { _id: 1, item: "apple" },
     $setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 100 }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

And the document is in this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/